# Get Wordpress post image attachment source into custom XML template

Tags: php, xml, wordpress

I am trying to load the image attachment source into a custom XML file, however it comes up with a Missing Attachment error, as shown [here](https://www.telecomsworldplc.co.uk/advice/xml-page/)

Here is the code I am using:

```
<?php
/**
 * Template Name: Custom XML Template - Csutom Feed
 */
$postCount = 5; // The number of posts to show in the feed
$posts = query_posts('showposts=' . $postCount);
header('Content-Type: '.feed_content_type('rss-http').'; charset='.get_option('blog_charset'), true);
echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="'.get_option('blog_charset').'"?'.'>';
?>
<rss version="2.0"
        xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/"
        xmlns:wfw="http://wellformedweb.org/CommentAPI/"
        xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
        xmlns:atom="http://www.w3.org/2005/Atom"
        xmlns:sy="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/syndication/"
        xmlns:slash="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/slash/"
        <?php do_action('rss2_ns'); ?>>
<channel>
        <title><?php bloginfo_rss('name'); ?> - Feed</title>
        <atom:link href="<?php self_link(); ?>" rel="self" type="application/rss+xml" />
        <link><?php bloginfo_rss('url') ?></link>
        <description><?php bloginfo_rss('description') ?></description>
        <lastBuildDate><?php echo mysql2date('D, d M Y H:i:s +0000', get_lastpostmodified('GMT'), false); ?></lastBuildDate>
        <language><?php echo get_option('rss_language'); ?></language>
        <sy:updatePeriod><?php echo apply_filters( 'rss_update_period', 'hourly' ); ?></sy:updatePeriod>
        <sy:updateFrequency><?php echo apply_filters( 'rss_update_frequency', '1' ); ?></sy:updateFrequency>
        <?php do_action('rss2_head'); ?>
        <?php while(have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
                <item>
                        <title><?php the_title_rss(); ?></title>
                        <link><?php the_permalink_rss(); ?></link>
                        <pubDate><?php echo mysql2date('D, d M Y H:i:s +0000', get_post_time('Y-m-d H:i:s', true), false); ?></pubDate>
                        <dc:creator><?php the_author(); ?></dc:creator>
                        <guid isPermaLink="false"><?php the_guid(); ?></guid>
                        <description><![CDATA[<?php the_excerpt_rss() ?>]]></description>
                        //------------LINE IN QUESTION--------------//
                        <image><?php the_attachment_link() ?></image>
                        <content><?php the_content_rss() ?></content>
                        <?php rss_enclosure(); ?>
                        <?php do_action('rss2_item'); ?>
                </item>
        <?php endwhile; ?>
</channel>
</rss>
```

Any ideas on where I am going wrong?

Comment: There is no attachment?

Comment: Hi there, there are definitely images attached to the posts. Confusing!

Comment: If you do this does it echo  the image src? `echo wp_get_attachment_image_src( get_post_thumbnail_id($post->ID), 'full');`

Comment: Tried that, and it makes the <image> tag blank

Comment: You should filter the output through tidy, most likely the output is not valid XML with string concatenation deluxe.

Answer (score 0):

We need to provide the *attachment ID* for [`the_attachment_link($attach_id)`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_attachment_link), so this is not the function you're looking for. To get the *Featured Image* of a post we use [`the_post_thumbnail()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_post_thumbnail).

If the post doesn't have a FI, we use [`get_childen()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_children) to get any image attached to a specific post and select one from there.